# How to get Spring Boot + Data Rest to resolve validation messages based on Accept-Language?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-data-rest

I've got an API application based on Spring Boot (1.2.0.RC2) and Spring Data Rest, using Hibernate bean validation (out-of-the-box).

In order to expose invalid input (400 Bad Request) to the API clients I've created an exception handler class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` which has the following method:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody ResponseEntity handleViolation(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
ErrorRepresentation.Builder builder = new ErrorRepresentation.Builder()    
    .withViolations(
        exception.getConstraintViolations().stream()
            .map(v -> {
                ErrorRepresentation.Builder violationBuilder = new ErrorRepresentation.Builder();
                violationBuilder.withDetail(v.getMessage());
                violationBuilder.withInternalRef(v.getPropertyPath().iterator().next().getName());
                return violationBuilder;
            })
            .map(ErrorRepresentation.Builder::build)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    builder.withStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    ErrorRepresentation error = builder.build();    
    return createResponseEntity(error);
}
```

Here I'm mapping `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation` into my own custom error representation class, which is then serialized to JSON. So far so good!

i18n is working, but only based on the default locale of the server environment.

I was hoping Spring had bootstrapped message interpolation automatically, such that the `Accept-Language` would be picked up and the `Locale` would be changed per request before message interpolation occurred.

Any hints on how to put this together?

Comment: just guess: add Locale argument to your method and you can use it then to do your i18n

Comment: @sodik It worked injecting the ```Locale``` into the method (seemed to enable ```AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver```), but then I guess I would have to do all the message resolving myself? As you can see from the updated code example, the ```ConstraintViolationException``` already comes with resolved messages.

Comment: hm.... another guess: try to find out something about http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/MessageInterpolator.html  and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getMessageTemplate()

Comment: Spring Boot registers the `FixedLocaleResolver` which always returns a fixed locale. If you don't want this just add the `AcceptHeaderLocalResolver` as a bean to your config (this will override the default).